# Three.js emissive materials don't cast shadow

Tags: three.js, shadow, react-three-fiber

#### Conext

I'm using three.js, @react-three/drei and @react-three/fiber.

I'm loading a GLTF file that contains emissive materials using

```
const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, '/model.glb')
```

When I inspect the loaded data like this:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(gltf.materials)) {
      const v = gltf.materials[key] as MeshStandardMaterial & Material
      if (!v.isMeshStandardMaterial) return

      console.log(key, v, v.emissive, v.emissiveIntensity, v.emissiveMap)
}
```

I can see that certain materials have a color set and their emissiveIntensity is equal to 1.

#### Problem

Objects made of these emissive materials load and display correctly on the scene. They have the desired color. There is, however, one problem. **I would like those emissive materials to behave like a directonalLight/pointLight - i.e. cast shadows and cause reflections.** Right now, they only display as shiny blobs, but their light doesn't *affect* other objects.

### Question

**How do I make emissive materials cast shadows and create reflections? Do I need a shader or is there some hidden option that I'm not seeing?**

Comment: You'll need to add a `PointLight` to the center of the object to simulate light shining on other objects. [Kind of like this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_shadowmap_pointlight).

Comment: I'm aware of this way to solve this; however, I would really like to avoid it if possible. It would mean either having to process the loaded gltf and automatically insert pointLights in the right places or manually figuring out where to put dozens of lights.

Comment: That’s the only way. Emissive materials don’t affect other objects’ lighting, so you have to add something that does.